# Room DAO Cursor replacement

Tags: android, android-room, android-cursor

Currently I am refactoring a bit old project and decided to use Room DAO. This project uses Cursor to display a long list of entities. Ok Room DAO has an abilility to return Cursor.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
public Cursor loadUsers();
```

But the official documentation discourage us to use it

> Caution: It's highly discouraged to work with the Cursor API because
>   it doesn't guarantee whether the rows exist or what values the rows
>   contain. Use this functionality only if you already have code that
>   expects a cursor and that you can't refactor easily.

Documentation proposes to do in this way

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
public List<User> loadUsers();
```

My concerns is that this will actually fetch all data from the table and hold them in a memory (Am I missing sth?). In contrast cursor holds just a bunch of data (window) and fetches a new portion on demand.

So the question is how to do large database queries using Room DAO keeping low memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, if you have a large database query for which you are relying upon cursor windows, you should be rethinking your UI. Users do not want to swipe through thousands of rows in a list, for example.

However, the Architecture Components' solution for your problem is [the Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/). You can have your DAO return a `DataSource.Factory` instead of a `Cursor` or `List`, and you can use that `DataSource.Factory` for delivering pages to your UI (e.g., a `RecyclerView`) as needed.